# How to print a server side text file on a client printer programically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, printing

I have a server side application which creates a series of text files on the server.  I need to allow a user to print one or more of the files directly on the client printer by clicking a button on a web page.  That should bring up a printer selection window and then commence printing the selected web pages.  I can handle the file selection and the printer selection windows but have not been able to get the files to print.  I located code on Code Project (http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/689325/Send-PDF-files-directly-to-client-printer-without) which was described as doing exactly what I need but for for PDF files.  I have attempted to adapt it to text files and the code runs without visible error, but nothing arrives at the printer and I do not know how to locate what happens after the code executes the value attribute of the Object tag of the web pages source code (see below).  I program in VB.Net.

Here is the object tag in the source code:

```
 <object id = "Object1" name="Txt1" 
type="file/txt" width="1" height="1" >
            <param  name='SRC' value='<%= SReportFileName %>'/>
</object>
```

Here is the code from the code behind file:

```
Partial Class ViewResults_PrintingReports
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Public SReportFileName As String = ""
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim PathName As String = ""
        Dim Uname As String = ""
        Dim Iyr As String = ""
        Dim Iwld As String = ""
        Dim Iqtr As String = ""
        Dim FName As String = ""
        Dim CNumber As String = ""
        Uname = "UserName"
        Iyr = "3"
        Iqtr = "1"
        FName = "ReportA"
        CNumber = "1"
        Iwld = "1"
        '       Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
        PathName = "~/Competitions/" & Uname & "/BP/" & "World" & Iwld & "/Reports/QtrRpts" & Iwld & "." & Iyr & Iqtr & "/" & FName & "." & Iwld & CNumber & ".txt"
        SReportFileName = PathName '// temp/mypdf.pdf 
        Try
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page), "MessagePopUp", "<script language=text/javascript>document.Txt1.printAll()</script>")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Problem printing file", , ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call javascript.
Here is the javascript

```
          function PrintFile(FilePath) {

                var printWin = window.open(FilePath, '','left=0,top=0,width=700,height=700,status=0');

                printWin.focus();
                printWin.print();

            }
```

This is the codebehind of the button

```
Dim FilePath As String
        FilePath = "This is your File Path"

        Dim PrintFile As String
        PrintFile = "PrintFile('" & FilePath & "')"
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "ntmtch", PrintFile, True)
```

Comment: I have put the function between script tags in my aspx file and placed the codebehind file.  When I run debug execution passes through the ScriptManager statement and end sub.  Nothing else happens.  Apparently the function is not being fired.  I have spent a lot of time reading and trying small changes but cannot get ti to work.  The java script does not seem to be getting called.